# Using CTE , i need to filter out the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named source_name whose populated data is given as below.

```
Date          Name
------        -------
2010-01-14    a
2010-01-15    b
2010-01-16    c
2010-01-17    bc
2010-01-18    bcc
2010-01-19    bd
2010-01-20    bddd
2010-01-13    be
2010-01-12    beeeee
2010-01-11    beee
2010-01-10    beee
2010-01-09    beee
```

I need a CTE query to return me the following result.
Here is my condition. If i select the @no_of_days = 2 and @date = '2010-01-14'
it must return me

```
2010-01-15    b
2010-01-16    c
2010-01-13    be
2010-01-12    beee
```

I mean if the @no_of_days is selected as any number, then i want the filter data to be exactly the same number of data from the given date to that incremented date till the given no_of_days and correspondingly the date below it. 
Another example if @no_of_days = 3 and @date = '2010-01-14'

```
2010-01-15    b
2010-01-16    c
2010-01-17    bc
2010-01-13    be
2010-01-12    beee
2010-01-11    beee
```

I need an help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;
WITH myTable([Date], [Name]) 
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM source_name
    WHERE [Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(day, (@no_of_days*-1), @date) AND DATEADD(day, @no_of_days, @date)
    AND [Date] != @Date

)
.... do something here.
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need a CTE for that, nor do I see how it could help.
But the [`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) function should allow you to write a where clause quite easily:

```
SELECT *
FROM source_name
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF( day, [Date], @Date )) BETWEEN 1 AND @no_of_days
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5cbf0/1)

EDIT: As @MatBailie rightly comments, if you need to sift through a large amount of indexed dates, you don't want to meddle with the value of the `Date` column before you compare it and `DATEADD` is your friend instead.

Comment: @ChrisLively *chuckle*

Comment: Even if there is an index on `[date]`, having referenced it inside two functions *(`DateDiff, and ABS`)* will mean that the index can't be used and the whole table will be scanned. I strongly recommend ***never*** putting search fields inside functions.  `[DATE] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -@no_of_days, @date) AND DATEADD(DAY, @no_of_days, @date)` does not have this problem *(as it now does a range seek on an indexed column, between two scalar constants)*.

Comment: @MatBailie That's what you get when the java people hop into SQL questions. :) I'd argue this is somewhat more readable and it depends on how large the table is. But point well taken!